# D3 Datamaps pop-up template when clicking on a country

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to show a pop-up with information regarding the selected country, by appending a new svg on top of the map.

This is the function being called every time a country is clicked:

```
        ...
        done: function(datamap) {
                datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {

                    map.selectedCountry(geography.properties.name);
                });
            }
        });

        map.addPlugin('selectedCountry', function(layer, country) {

                    map.svg.selectAll('.datamap').append('g')
                    .attr("width", 100)
                    .attr("height", 100)
                    .style("fill", "black")
        });
```

Nevertheless, I do not see any change in the map, even though if I inspect the element I can see that a new `g` element has been added.